# Not able to receive 'Continued' status from waitpid using the nix crate

Tags: debugging, unix, rust, ptrace, waitpid

I'm experimenting with the nix crate in order to debug child processes. I would like to receive events when the child process stops, continues and exits. Stoppages and exits are reported using the `waitpid` function. I'm having trouble receiving the continued status though.

I tried to convert my code to a minimum reproduceable example and hoping someone is able to spot the problem.

```
fn main() {
    // fork here
    let res = unsafe { fork().unwrap() };

    if res.is_child() {
        traceme().unwrap();
        unsafe {
            breakpoint();
        }
    } else {
        let status = waitpid(Pid::from_raw(-1), Some(WaitPidFlag::WCONTINUED)).unwrap();
        let pid = status.pid().unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", status);
        println!("Calling continue....");
        cont(pid, None).unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", waitpid(Pid::from_raw(-1), None).unwrap());
    }
}
```

is producing the following output:

```
Stopped(Pid(28411), SIGTRAP)
Calling continue....
Exited(Pid(28411), 0)
```

Comment: `waitpid` only sees events that occur while in the `waitpid` function, but here the `Continued` signal is sent while you are outside `waitpid` and so is not seen. You will need to call `cont` from another thread or process.

Comment: But note that even if you call `waitpid` in a loop, there is always a risk of missing events that occur between calls.

Comment: @Jmb the [linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) reads "If a child has already changed state, then these calls return immediately. Otherwise they block until either a child changes state or a signal handler interrupts the call (assuming that system calls are not automatically restarted using the SA_RESTART flag of sigaction(2)). In the remainder of this page, a child whose state has changed and which has not yet been waited upon by one of these system calls is termed waitable.". The way I read this it seems it's not really possible to "miss" events.

Comment: My bad, you're right you should see the `Continued` signal if you were waiting for it, but the second time you call `waitpid` you pass `None` which ignores the `Continued` signals.